# Is it more efficient to use a common empty function instead of creating a new one in each class instance?

Tags: javascript, function, memory

Let's say I have a class that is designed to have some callbacks added to it later on.

```
function myclass() {
    this.onSomething = function () {};
    this.onOtherThing = function () {};

    this.something = function () {
        // stuff
        this.onSomething();
    };

    this.otherThing = function () {
        // other stuff
        this.onOtherThing();
    };
}
```

I can't have `this.onSomething` and `this.onOtherThing` being `undefined` or `null` because when they are called in `something()` and `otherThing()`, an error will be thrown, stating that their type is not a function.

Since those empty functions are needed, but they use memory, is the class going to be more memory efficient if I did this?

```
function myclass() {
    this.onSomething = empty;
    this.onOtherThing = empty;
    ...
}

function empty() {

}
```

This way each class instance's properties point to the same empty function, instead of creating new functions every time. I assume defining an empty method doesn't take a lot of memory, but still... is this technically better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the fact that a new function is created for every instance of your class. In order to have this shared across all instances you can declare it on the prototype of the class:

```
var MyClass = function() {
    this.something = function () {
        // stuff
        this.onSomething();
    };

    this.otherThing = function () {
        // other stuff
        this.onOtherThing();
    };
}

MyClass.prototype.onSomething = function() {};
MyClass.prototype.onOtherThing = function() {};
```

This way, the methods will be shared by all instances.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to `return true` or `return false` instead of returning empty functions.
or best you can use :

```
function myclass() {
    this.onSomething = false;
    this.onOtherThing = false;
    ...
}
```

as per your comment you can try :

```
 function myclass() {
  this.onSomething = empty(); 
  this.onOtherThing = empty();   
      ... }

 function empty() { 
   //return something
   return true;
 }
```

Comment: Because when `something()` calls `this.onSomething`, it will throw an error: `Uncaught TypeError: false is not a function`

Comment: okay. you can try `function myclass() {
    this.onSomething = empty();
    this.onOtherThing = empty();
    ...
}

function empty() {
//return something 
return true;
}`

Comment: Again. `empty()` returns `true`, so `this.onSomething = empty();` means `this.onSomething` is `true`. When `something()` calls `this.onSomething`, I will get `Uncaught TypeError: this.onSomething is not a function` since... it's a boolean value and not an actual function.